# How to change email color without having to change href settings?

Tags: hyperref

I am trying to change my email color, which uses href, without changing the \hypersetup.

```
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks   = true, 
  urlcolor     = blue, 
  linkcolor    = blue, 
  citecolor   = blue
}

\author{random name\\ {mailto:random}{random}}
```

I want the urlcolors to be blue but I don't want the email color to be blue. How would I change this?

Comment: I want the email color to be black

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a macro called `\email` which changes the value of `urlcolor` temporarily to `black`.

[image]

Observe the string's color: black.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks = true, 
  urlcolor = blue, linkcolor = blue, citecolor = blue}
\newcommand\email[2]{\hypersetup{urlcolor=black}%
    \href{mailto:#1}{#2}\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue}}

\begin{document}
\email{random.name@random.address}{Random Name}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be brackets around \email[2]?

Comment: @kdf - `\newcommand\email[2]{...}` and `\newcommand{\email}[2]{...}` are equally valid from a syntactical point of view.

Comment: I'm not sure if it worked. To specify, I want to change the email color in the titling page, which is before \begin{document}.

Comment: @kdf - For the `\email` macro to work, it most certainly has to be defined *after* `hyperref` is loaded. I'm not sure what is entailed by your statement "I'm not sure if it worked." So far, you've provided almost no information about your document setup -- other than the fact that you load the `hyperref` package and run `\hypersetup` at some point. Do feel free to provide some usable information about your document setup, including how you're setting up the title page and how and/or where you're trying to use `\email`.

Comment: It should work fine — just put the `\email` command inside the `\author` command. If that doesn’t work, can you say more specifically what you mean by “it doesn’t work” — it gives a compilation error, or the email address doesn’t come out black, or what?

Comment: It duplicates the email. So instead of just showing the name, it shows both the email and the name. random.name@random.addressRandom Name

Comment: @kdf - I've just posted a screenshot of the output produced by executing `\email{random.name@random.address}{Random Name}` in the example above. If *you* aren't getting "Random Name" (in black, of course) as the output, I can only surmise that you did *not* copy the code the way I posted it. Are you getting any error or warning messages? If so, what do the messages say?

Comment: I've copy and pasted the exact code and it says "Latex Error: Missing \begin{document}"

Comment: @kdf - Now we're starting to get somewhere in terms of actual document-related information. Absolutely, the lack of a `\begin{document}` instruction is fatal. That said, I can definitely spot a `\begin{document}` instruction in the code I posted. Given the fatal error, I'm actually quite curious about how you manage to generate `random.name@random.addressRandom Name` as the output of `\email{random.name@random.address}{Random Name}`. Please do say a wee bit more about how you're using the `\email` macro -- and about your document setup in general.

Comment: But isn't the \title, \date, and the \author written before \begin{document}?

Comment: @kdf - You ask, "But isn't the `\title`, `\date`, and the `\author` written before `\begin{document}`" These three instructions can be placed either before or after `\begin{document}`; however, they produce *no output*. Output is only generated by `\maketitle` (or something similar), and `\maketitle` must not occur before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @kdf - I see no `\email` directive inside your `\author` statement in the code that was contained in the comment you appear to have deleted in the meantime. Whatever is going wrong therefore cannot be caused by the use of `\email`.